# Xcode 8 : Unable to Accept License Agreement on OS X EL Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: xcode8

I have downloaded Xcode 8 from AppStore, on clicking Xcode icon it is showing [image: Apple License Agreement Window] after clicking on Agree button it is asking username and password. On entering the username and password nothing is happening.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: But still it's correctly tagged for Xcode & it's real issue regarding dev environment. I'm also facing similar issue.

Comment: @iOSGeek This is a software installation issue. Not a programming question. This should be posted to http://apple.stackexchange.com or the Apple developer forums.

Comment: i agree @rmaddy Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem i was facing "Xcode 8 : Unable to Accept License Agreement on OS X EL Capitan 10.11.6" is resolved.

**Cause :** It was blocked due to **Symantec and Web Sense installed in my macbook**

**Resolution :** Start your mackbook in **Safe Mode** (in safemode there is no Symantec and web sense installed) and then install Xcode 8.

To start macbook in safe mode try this : [OS X El Capitan: Start up in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21875?locale=en_US)